# How to validate 2 nested json using Pydantic model in python?

Tags: python, pydantic

```json
test1 = {
  "abx": [
    {
      "name": "toyota",
      "colors": "abc",
      "demo": [
        {
          "name1": "pqr",
          "surname": "abc",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name2": "demo",
              "nameid": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "suzuki",
      "colors": "deq",
      "demo": [
        {
          "name1": "abc",
          "surname": "asd",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name2": "demo1",
              "nameid": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have 2 nested JSON and both responses have shuffle values. I wanted to match using Pydantic models for testing in Python.

Is there any way to compare, validate both responses?

Comment: What do you need to validate? What needs to match? What is the expected behavior after defining the pydantic classes? Nested JSON just translates to nested python classes... but it is unclear what you expect the classes to do.

Answer (score 1):

**A nested JSON can simply be represented by nested Pydantic models**. Each object can be mapped to a model, and that model can have attributes that are other Pydantic models or a list of Pydantic models.

---

(*The following examples are valid as of Pydantic v1*)

You start with the innermost objects:

```json
{
    "name2": "demo1",
    "nameid": "2",
}
```

which can be represented as:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

class Column(BaseModel):
    name2: str
    nameid: constr(regex="[0-9]+")  # See: https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr
```

```
In [2]: raw = {"name2": "demo1", "nameid": "2"}
In [3]: col = Column(**raw)
In [4]: col.name2
Out[4]: 'demo1'
In [5]: col.nameid
Out[5]: '2'
```

If one of the values is wrong, Pydantic would raise a validation error:

```
In [6]: raw = {"name2": 1, "nameid": True}
In [7]: col = Column(**raw)
...
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Column
nameid
  string does not match regex "[0-9]+" (type=value_error.str.regex; pattern=[0-9]+)
```

Then you move up to each `Column`'s parent object:

```json
{
    "name1": "abc",
    "surname": "asd",
    "columns": [
        {"name2": "demo1", "nameid": "2"},
    ],
}
```

which can then be represented as:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist

class Demo(BaseModel):
    name1: str
    surname: str
    columns: conlist(Column, min_items=1)  # See: https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#arguments-to-conlist
```

where we reuse the previous `Column` class definition, to say that the `columns` attribute is a list of `Column`'s. Pydantic can instantiate and validate each attribute of `Column` under `Demo`:

```
In [8]: raw
Out[8]: {'name1': 'abc', 'surname': 'asd', 'columns': [{'name2': 'demo1', 'nameid': '2'}]}
In [9]: demo = Demo(**raw)
In [11]: demo.name1
Out[11]: 'abc'
In [13]: demo.surname
Out[13]: 'asd'
In [14]: demo.columns
Out[14]: [Column(name2='demo1', nameid='2')]
In [15]: demo.columns[0].name2
Out[15]: 'demo1'
In [16]: demo.columns[0].nameid
Out[16]: '2'
```

Again, if any of the values are wrong (whether from the outer attributes or from the innermost attributes), Pydantic will raise a validation error:

```
In [20]: raw
Out[20]: {'name1': 'abc', 'surname': None, 'columns': [{'name2': 'demo1', 'nameid': '2'}]}
In [21]: demo = Demo(**raw)
...
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Demo
surname
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

```
In [27]: raw
Out[27]: {'name1': 'abc', 'surname': 'asd', 'columns': [{'name2': None, 'nameid': '2'}]}
In [28]: demo = Demo(**raw)
...
ValidationError: 1 validation error for Demo
columns -> 0 -> name2
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

Then after that, you move up again to each `Demo`'s parent object

```json
{
    "name": "suzuki",
    "colors": "deq",
    "demo": [
        {
            "name1": "abc",
            "surname": "asd",
            "columns": [
                {"name2": "demo1", "nameid": "2"},
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

which can be represented as

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist

class Car(BaseModel):
    name: str
    colors: str
    demo: conlist(Demo, min_items=1)
```

where, same as what we did for `Column`, we have a `demo` attribute that is modeled as a list of `Demo` objects. Pydantic can handle nested initialization and validation of `demo` which includes its inner `Column` class.

Finally, you'll reach the uppermost object:

```py
test1 = {
    "abx": [
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

which has an `abx` attribute that's a list of `Car` objects

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist

class Test(BaseModel):
    abx: conlist(Car, min_items=1)
```

```
In [3]: obj = Test(**test1)
In [4]: obj
Out[4]: Test(abx=[Car(name='toyota', colors='abc', demo=[Demo(name1='pqr', surname='abc', columns=[Column(name2='demo', nameid='1')])]), Car(name='suzuki', colors='deq', demo=[Demo(name1='abc', surname='asd', columns=[Column(name2='demo1', nameid='2')])])])

In [5]: obj.abx[1]
Out[5]: Car(name='suzuki', colors='deq', demo=[Demo(name1='abc', surname='asd', columns=[Column(name2='demo1', nameid='2')])])

In [6]: obj.abx[1].demo[0]
Out[6]: Demo(name1='abc', surname='asd', columns=[Column(name2='demo1', nameid='2')])
```

You can also stop modeling anywhere, for example, stop at modeling a `Car` and validate from the raw `abx` object:

```
In [15]: car1 = Car(**test1['abx'][0])
In [16]: car1
Out[16]: Car(name='toyota', colors='abc', demo=[Demo(name1='pqr', surname='abc', columns=[Column(name2='demo', nameid='1')])])

In [17]: car2 = Car(**test1['abx'][1])
In [18]: car2
Out[18]: Car(name='suzuki', colors='deq', demo=[Demo(name1='abc', surname='asd', columns=[Column(name2='demo1', nameid='2')])])
```

Again, if you have an error, even somewhere in the inner `Column` model, you'll get a validation error.

The good thing about this is that you can test and validate each object in turn, from the innermost ones up to the outermost one. For more details about the usage of `constr` and `conlist`, check Pydantic docs for [Constrained Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#constrained-types) as well as the other [Field Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/) and [Validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/) for more complex validations.